# Immigration rules when connecting though Toronto Pearson to another Canadian airport

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, security

Please could someone help being as not very clear and this will be my first ever connection flight on my own.

Basically I am flying from the UK and need to Pass though Toronto Pearson International to get a connection to Sudbury airport, and it is giving me a 2 hour connection time, my fear is with security and customs this will not be long enough being as will be in totally new surrounding,or would I do most of my customs in Sudbury because that's my final destination.

The only other time had a connection flight with fellow family members we had 2 an half hours and it was classed as "long connection wait" but we had to run for the plane in the end.

Comment: Is this all on one ticket, or are the two flights on different tickets? And if you get delayed and miss the onward flight, how much of a wait is there for the next one?

Comment: to add to @Gagravarr comment if the two flights are on one ticket then it is the airlines problem if you miss your connecting flight. IE you will most likely be rescheduled automatically onto the next available flight at no extra charge.

Comment: thank you guys @Gagravarr and davidb it will be a 2 hour connection time in Toronto, orther wise if end up missing the flight, the next flight is about another 6 later. but my flight will be booked as a whole journey not like UK to Toronto and then Toronoto then sudbury

Comment: If your flight is on time, and they'll sell you a ticket for it, then they expect that pretty much everyone will make it. If your inbound flight is delayed, bring a book as you'll probably have a 6 hour wait...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, unless your plane is delayed. The other airline will know that you have landed and are in the airport and will make every effort not to leave without you.

Answer (score 6):

You will **always** clear customs on your first entry point to Canada. That will be Toronto for you. Even if you happen to get in right after a very large plane of people who all need a lot of customs attention, you won't wait more than 30 minutes in line for customs. I think a two hour connection will be fine. You almost certainly don't have a terminal change (that would be likely only with an airline change) so once through customs things will go pretty quickly for you.

As always a vital piece of information is whether it's all booked as one ticket. When it is, you know that

- the airline thinks that's a reasonable connection time
- if your incoming flight is late and you miss your connection, the airline will take care of you. Which might mean you read your book for a few more hours than you wanted, but you won't have to shell out for a replacement plane ticket or the like

I rarely connect in Toronto (I believe I've done it exactly once and that was domestic to domestic) but I land in it all the time, and leave from it all the time, and since you need to clear customs that's essentially what you are doing. Two hours will be more than enough. Even if your incoming flight is up to 30 minutes late you may fret, but you will make you connection.

Enjoy Sudbury! Hope it's a little warmer by the time you get there! If you're leaving this week, pack **warm**!

Comment: I had to wait over an hour and a half at YYZ last time I came back from overseas- shameful. Suggest he makes a fuss and jump the queue if things are looking tight.

Comment: Must have either been two planes, or not enough customs staff. I got Nexus so I don't wait any more, unless I'm traveling with a non Nexus companion. Even then 20 minutes has been my longest wait (though it often feels a whole lot longer.)

Comment: the separate line for non-citizens was significantly slower and I got into that one accidentally (the sign said the opposite of where they were directing people), but that's the one he'll be taking. I'm sure he'll be okay, but I'd speak up if the time is getting down. Sometimes a couple big planes arrive from Asia or south of the US and it goes slower than it should in an allegedly first-world country.